# GetLastError returns 998 when CreateWindow failed and returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi

In **main.cpp**:

```c
#include "window.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    Window main_window(hInstance, nCmdShow);
    main_window.Intitialize(CS_HREDRAW, NULL, LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW), (WIDE_CHAR) "Application", (WIDE_CHAR) "WindowName");
    return main_window.Show();
}
```

In **window.h**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef _WINDOW_H_
    #define _WINDOW_H_

#include <windows.h>

typedef wchar_t* WIDE_CHAR;
typedef HINSTANCE INSTANCE;
typedef HWND HANDLE_WINDOW;
typedef tagWNDCLASSEXW WINDOW_CLASS;

LRESULT Procedure(HANDLE_WINDOW, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

class Window {
  private:
    INSTANCE instance;
    int show_command;
    WINDOW_CLASS window_object;
    HANDLE_WINDOW handle;

  public:
    Window(INSTANCE instance, int show_command) {
        this->instance = instance;
        this->show_command = show_command;
    }

    void Intitialize(UINT style, HICON icon, HCURSOR cursor, HBRUSH background, WIDE_CHAR class_name, WIDE_CHAR title) {
        window_object.cbSize = sizeof(WINDOW_CLASS);
        window_object.cbClsExtra = 0;
        window_object.cbWndExtra = 0;
        window_object.hInstance = instance;
        window_object.lpfnWndProc = Procedure;

        window_object.style = style;
        window_object.hIcon = icon;
        window_object.hCursor = cursor;
        window_object.hbrBackground = background;
        window_object.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        window_object.lpszClassName = class_name;
        window_object.hIconSm = NULL;

        RegisterClassExW(&window_object);
        printf("%lld", GetLastError());

        handle = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, class_name, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1080, 720, NULL, NULL, instance, NULL);
    }

    int Show() {
        ShowWindow(handle, show_command);
        UpdateWindow(handle);

        MSG message;
        while (GetMessageW(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessageW(&message);
        }

        return message.wParam;
    }
};

LRESULT Procedure(HANDLE_WINDOW handle, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(handle);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(handle, message, wParam, lParam);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

I tried to wrap the Win32 interface and tried to make a window, but I always got stuck in some weird places, like the Unicode...

First of all, I can't fully understand the use and conversion of wide characters. I think a large part of the reason for the failure of window registration and window creation is in the use of wide and normal characters.
Secondly, I don't understand why I can't use the namespace "std", once I use it, even window registration fails.

Comment: `I don't understand why I can't use the namespace "std", once I use it, even window registration fails.` What?

Comment: Among other things, you are calling DefWindowProc instead of DefWindowProcW. (More generally, you are mixing ANSI and Unicode.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `(WIDE_CHAR) "Application"` and `(WIDE_CHAR) "WindowName"` to `Intitialize`.

As you defined

```
typedef wchar_t* WIDE_CHAR;
```

the parameters are *NARROW* characters cast to *WIDE* characters. When `CreateWindowExW` tries to access them, it goes out-of-bounds (because wide string is twice as long as narrow), resulting in error:

> ```
> ERROR_NOACCESS
>
> 998 (0x3E6)
>
> Invalid access to memory location.
> ```

according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--500-999-

Do this instead:

```
main_window.Intitialize(CS_HREDRAW, NULL, LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), 
    (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW), L"Application", L "WindowName");
```

Comment: sorry... I have tried this... but it warns `ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'WIDE_CHAR' {aka 'wchar_t*'}` and the title of window only shows "W" but not "WindowName"... I can't understand...

Comment: @Tatsukana please show what you tried, and the line that cased this error

Comment: @Tatsukana string literals are `const` data. Change `Initialize()` to take `const wchar_t*` instead of `wchar_t*`. Also, you need to use `DefWindowProcW()` instead of `DefWindowProc()`. And, `Procedure()` needs the `__stdcall` calling convention.

Comment: @Tatsukana please see Remy’s comment above about ‘const’